# Blazor JS Interop getElementById to get component reference

Tags: blazor, getelementbyid, blazor-jsinterop

I need, in Blazor, get a reference to a component by its ID.
Note: Not using ElementReference, as it is for generic code.

I've used this JS Interop script to do a focus and it works fine for me:

```cs
public async Task Focus(string elementId){
        await js.InvokeVoidAsync("eval", $@"document.getElementById(""elementId}"").focus()");
}
```

But what I need from Blazor is get only a reference to the element (the component), that is, the return of:  `document.getElementById(""{elementId}"")`
sending it elementId as a parameter.

Is it possible?

Edit: I've tried with this script but always returns null when calling it from Blazor:

```html
<script>
        window.GetElementById = (myId) => {
            return document.getElementById(myId);
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you expand on the use-case?  You probably don't need this.

Comment: Do you want a javascript HTMLElement or a blazor ElementReference?

Comment: Cool Developer,  It could be enough for me, getting in Blazor the return of this JS expression:  document.getElementById ("myId")

Answer (score 4):

### Update

To specifically answer your question.

You're calling with InvokeVoidAsync which returns a void as you see. If you call with InvokeAsync you get an empty JsonDocument object returned.

So no, you can't get a usable reference back from the js call.

#### Previous Answer before clarification of question

============================================================
If I read your question correctly, you want to set the focus to an html element `id` that you're generating "generically".

The answer below shows how to set the focus using either `Element` or `id`.

Add a `site.js` to *wwwroot* with the following code:

```
window.SetElementFocus = function (element) {
    element.focus();
    return element === true;
}

window.SetFocusByElementId = function (elementId) {
    var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    element.focus();
    return element === true;
}
```

Reference the js file in your startup file (this is for server)

```
    <script src="/site.js"></script>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
```

And then here's a demo page.

```
@page "/Test6"
<div class="m-2">
    <input type="text" @ref="Input1" placeholder="Input 1" id="input1" />
</div>

<div class="m-2">
    <input type="text" @ref="Input2" placeholder="Input 2" id="input2" />
</div>

<div class="m-2">
    <input type="text" @ref="Input3" placeholder="Input 3" id="input3" />
</div>

<div class="m-2 p-2">
    <button class="btn btn-dark me-1" @onclick="() => Focus(1)">Element Focus 1</button>
    <button class="btn btn-dark me-1" @onclick="() => Focus(2)">Element Focus 2</button>
    <button class="btn btn-dark me-1" @onclick="() => Focus(3)">Element Focus 3</button>
</div>

<div class="m-2 p-2">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary me-1" @onclick="() => FocusById(1)">Id Focus 1</button>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary me-1" @onclick="() => FocusById(2)">Id Focus 2</button>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary me-1" @onclick="() => FocusById(3)">Id Focus 3</button>
</div>


@code {

    [Inject] private IJSRuntime _js { get; set; }

    private ElementReference Input1;
    private ElementReference Input2;
    private ElementReference Input3;

    private async Task Focus(int no)
    {
        var input = no switch
        {
            1 => Input1,
            2 => Input2,
            _ => Input3
        };
        await _js.InvokeAsync<bool>("SetElementFocus", input);
    }

    private async Task FocusById(int no)
    {
        var input = no switch
        {
            1 => "input1",
            2 => "input2",
            _ => "input3"
        };
        await _js.InvokeAsync<bool>("SetFocusByElementId", input);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really focusing, because it already works well for me.  What I want is just getting in Blazor the element, i. e. the return of this JS expression: document.getElementById("myId"), without focusing the element;  sending the myId as a parameter from Blazor.

Comment: What type of "object" are you expecting to get back and what do you want to do with it?  You're calling it with `InvokeVoidAsync` which returns a void.  Calling it with `InvokeAsync` 
 gets you a JsonDocument object that contains nothing.

Comment: Just expecting return an object .net type. The InvokeVoidAsync was just as a working focusing example, but what I need is return the element, with a script  like the one I added at the end, but it returns null.

Comment: Whatever you were planning to do with the returned object, you need to rethink your design.  What do you want it for?

Comment: I really have very little knowledge of JavaScript, so I ask. If there is no other option, then I would look for another solution. I really appreciate your help but my question is specifically if that is possible. From your answer I must assume that no.

Comment: @Antonito, from what I understand, you want to manipulate an element like you do in  javascript from blazor?

Comment: @Antonito - I've updated the answer with No you can't get anything back.  Time for a rethink!